# Solving an inequality

Tags: inequality

Name the property that justifies each statement.

If $-3x < 24$, then $x > -8$.

Comment: What did you try to showing the inequality?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, did you try to show the inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is the Additive Inverse

If $a < b$ then $-a > -b$

If $a > b$ then $-a < -b$

This is really the same as multiplying by $(-1)$, and that is why it changes direction.

http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/inequality-properties.html

so in your case, it'd be (after dividing both sides by 3)

$-3x < 24 \implies -x < 8$

multiplying both sides by $(-1)$ and according to the Additive Inverse you'd change the sign..

$(-1)(-x) < (-1)8 \implies x >-8$

Comment: Almost but how about the 3?  That would require the reciprocal property of real numbers in order to cancel it out on one side.

Comment: when you multiply/divide by a positive number the inequality remains the same.

Comment: I would still think you would have to justify why you divide by 3.

Comment: Well, there isn't a particular property that defines it, multiplication and division of inequalities by positive numbers is equivalent to traditional multiplication and division.